# Embedded videos and bandwidth usage

Tags: bandwidth, video-embedding

If I was to embed a short video into a webpage of a website, but the actual video itself resided on a 3rd party server, would the website that has the embedded code use a small amount of its allocated bandwidth to play the video (because the video is actually located on another server) or would it use a larger amount of allocated bandwidth because you are still effectively watching the video through that website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only bandwidth required by the viewed webpage would be whatever code is being used to direct the browser viewing that webpage to the third party.

For example if you embed a youtube video on your webpage all your server send the browser viewing the webpage is your html file.

All the actual video and video player data is either browser side or on the part of the third party.

Tl;Dr
no bandwidth used to play the video, negligible amount of bandwidth used to send the extra line of html to tell the browser to play it.

Comment: Nps and happy holidays ! :D